# Set Password in phpmyadmin on 22.04 fails

Tags: 22.04, phpmyadmin

Installed phpmyadmin (5.1.1deb5ubuntu1) on Ubuntu 22.04 and tried to do a Set Password SQL statement but got a syntax error -- You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server for the right syntax to use near 'password('*paswrd*')' at line 1.
Where can I find the correct syntax for the MySQL version that comes with 22.04?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that with 'Set password SQL statement' you mean this:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql_set_password_statement.htm

Then, I guess that you are confusing the `PASSWORD` function and the `SET PASSWORD` statement. The statement is used to change a user password:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR USER goofy 'mypassword';
```

The function is used to hash a password:

```
SELECT PASSWORD('mypassword');
```

Comment: I mean the Set Password for User statement in SQL.It does not work with MYSQL 8.1.2 which is the version in 22.04. It returns the comment in my post.

Comment: @E.Porter This is why I asked you to edit your question with exact details, but you failed to do that. If people have to guess what you mean, you are unlikely to get helpful answers.

Comment: @Nmath Isn't my edited post detailed enough ?

Comment: @Nmath the "Set Password for User statement in SQL" is the first command that I wrote. Do you confirm that you are typing *exactly* the syntax that I wrote? as E. Porter wrote, you must clearly write the command that you typed and the output that you got. A typical problem is when the password contains some strange character.

Comment: @Nmath Should I edit the main post or should I just do an add comment?

Comment: Always edit the main post because this is a Q&A site not a discussion forum. A new visitor to a question should never have to read a comment chain to understand the question. Keep the question up-to-date

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using a terminal and doing an 'alter user' in mysql.
The command was: ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '*root password*';
Also, now using root as the login to phpmyadmin produces a User Accounts tab in phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I was able to solve it by using `mysql -u root -p` with this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34322053

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).